# How do i add XAML to an existing C++ DirectX windows 8 app?

Tags: xaml, directx, windows-8.1

I have a fully working C++ game, all done and ready to go... But i'd like to add some adverts to it. I have found out that in order to do that you require XAML.

How do I go about putting a XAML page on top of my DirectX C++ application so I can display the adverts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Jimmyt1988 - take a look at SwapChainPanel (newer in Win8.1 and preferred) and/or SwapChainBackgroundPanel.

Some resources for you:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.swapchainpanel.aspx
- http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-SwapChainPanel-00cb688b
- http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Windows-Camp/Developing-Windows-8-Metro-style-apps-in-Cpp/Building-Apps-with-Cpp-XAML-and-DirectX

Hope this helps!

Comment: OH my goddddd... thank youuuuu! now I know what to look for... I'll keep you updated on my progress, perhaps you can help me out more when I get some code down? :)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the resources Tim mentioned in his answer above, also check out:  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LpLMSbxKEIU
That helped me get started with DirectX on Windows 8.

[This should ideally be a comment, but I am new and I don't have enough reputation points]